# Is there a way to adjust browser created white space when using text-orientation: upright?

Tags: html, css

I have created a vertical text headline for my page, but the spacing between letters is completely different in Chrome than Firefox. I have tried to adjust letter spacing but that only changes it when `text-orientation: upright;` is not applied.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Long Text</h1>
</body>
```

[Google (left) vs Firefox (right) upright text display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIpR2.png)

Comment: can you try using a !important after text-orientation:upright;

Comment: tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: can you please post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Did you try setting a specific font?

Comment: Yes, i used a specific font for all elements.

Comment: Font choice seems to have a large impact on vertical white spacing, I used "Lucida Sans Unicode" originally and vertical white space in chrome was much larger than in Firefox. I then switched to "Helvetica" and the vertical white space difference was much less significant between browsers. In general chrome adds more vertical white space.